# URL redirect regular expressions redirecting all after first viriable

Tags: redirect, urls

I would very much like to redirect

```
https://www.store.nl/?prodcategory=literal%20category%20name&productid=12345
```

to

```
https://www.store.nl/literal-category-name/
```

I'm trying to add the redirect in Redirection Plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: For plugin-related questions it's best to contact the plugin author or consult their documentation. You could also do this using .htaccess, though that too would be a bit off-topic as the question is about redirects rather than specific to WP.

Comment: Since it is a general regular expression question, I hoped someone over here might have an answer.

Comment: You might have more luck on StackOverflow. On this site people mostly answer more WP-specific questions. :)